# XAML: Problems with resolving Classes in Namespaces

Tags: xaml, namespaces

....

Hi All,

I cannot find the Error in my Code. I have a XAML File and it wont find the Class
in the Namespace. The Namespace still exists. The class too. And XAML accepts the
Namespac declared by "`xmlns:n="clr-namespace:ERDBuilder.Resources.Tools"`.But
the XAML throws an Error, that the Class doesnt exist in this Namespace. I dont
know how to fix this. See the Picture for more Details about the Problem.

[image]

The File Brushes.xaml are here:

[image]

Thank you all for Help!

Comment: Is the module outdated or too new? Sometimes public classes are added/removed depending on the version.

Comment: Hi Dylan, the module (NoiseGenerator.cs) still exist the whole Time. I have not done anything with dependencies. If it is outdated, how can I fix this ?

Comment: I allready rebuild everything. Cleaned up everything. Restarted VS2012 and rebooted the machine.

Comment: You'd need to update whatever framework. Say if it's Silverlight 2 you'd need the Silverlight 4 SDK. But you have to be certain that what you want exposed is available in said SDK

Comment: You may also want to append the class to the namespace.

Comment: It's no SDK stuff. It still worked allready. But now it wont. I have cleaned up the files and structured it in Subfolders. Walked over multiple Times to fix the Namespaces and Using directives in XAML, CLasses and Code Behind Files. But the XAML Files I can not fix, because I dont know how.

Comment: The Framework I'm using is .NET 4.5. Do you mean I should update it ?

Comment: Does the updated project name match in all the usings? If it doesn't this may be the result.

Comment: "You may also want to append the class to the namespace" >> I have done this by typing "namespace ERDBuilder.Resources.Tools" in the NoiseGenerator.cs File.

Comment: "Does the updated project name match in all the usings? If it doesn't this may be the result" >> I will check this again.

Comment: It seems that only the XAML Files have this problem. All native or not-XAML Files will still work with the Namespaces. All Errors only in the XAML Files. What does that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

What's the application type is it WPF? Silverlight? Metro?

I've noticed that in Metro apps you can do something like :

xmlns:n="using:ERDBuilder.Resources.Tools"

You might wish to try that one out.

Comment: It is a WPF Application. I tried xmlns:n="using:ERDBuilder.Resources.Tools" instead of xmlns:n="clr-namespace:ERDBuilder.Resources.Tools". But this only change the Error Message ("using..." instead of "clr-namespace...")

Comment: It seems that only the XAML Files have this problem. All native or not-XAML Files will still work with the Namespaces. All Errors only in the XAML Files. What does that mean ?